# Powerpivot percentage calculation not showing expected results

Tags: excel, powerpivot

The below link explains my pivot layout.

[My Pivot table in Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6okPBi3TOltYmlsbWdDTllXbDQ/edit?usp=sharing)

I am trying to calculate percentage escalation on sales which is (Escalation/Total Sell).  For this, I have created calculated column in powerpivot and use in pivot table with average aggregation.  The results from Pivot are not in line with actual calculated averages.

Where as the Contingency and Margin percentages are seems to be correct due to the fact that they have same percentage for all records.  Could someone point out what I am doing wrong here and how could I fix this issue?

I am sure this is bread and butter for experts but not for me as I am just starting to learn powerpivot.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can use a calculated measure to accomplish this instead of a calculated column.  The correct escalation % you are showing in your file is actually doing sum(escalation)/sum(total sell). To do this, enter the following formula in one of the empty cells in the calculation area:

```
Escalation%:=Sum(Range[dbescl2])/Sum(Range[dbtotalsell])
```

Here's a [help article](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/create-a-calculated-field-in-power-pivot-HA102836915.aspx) on creating calculated field.